# Building a Log In page with PHP and MySQL Project

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I am creating a login form, profile page and logout, but when I receive a wrong username message on the page and click the x button, it does not close. Also, when I add just the username and click on the log in button, the page goes blank. Could someone assist me in identifying what is askew here?

```
    <?php

        /*
            STEPS WE NEED TO TAKE...

            1. Build Login HTML form
            2. Check if form has been submitted
            3. Validate form data
            4. Add form data to variables
            5. Connect to database
            6. Query the database for username submitted
            6.1 If no entries: show error message
            7. Store basic user data from database in variables
            8. Verify stored hashed password with the one submitted in the form  
            8.1 If invalid: show error message
            9. Start a session & create session variables
            10. Redirect to a "profile page"
            10.1 Provide link to "logout" page
            10.2 Add cookie clear to logout page
            10.3 Provide link to log back in
            11. Close the MySQL connection
        */

        if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

            // build a function to validate data
            function validateFormData($formData) {
                $formData = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($formData)));
                return $formData;
            }

            // create variables
             // wrap the data with our function
            $formUser = validateFormData($_POST['username']);
            $formPass = validateFormData($_POST['password']);

            // connect to database
            include('connection.php');

            // create SQL query
            $query = "SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username='$formUser'";
            //store the result
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            // verify if result is returned
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                // store basic user data in variables
                while($row - mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $user   = $row['username'];
                    $email   = $row['email'];
                    $hashedPass   = $row['password'];
                }

                // verify hashed password with the typed password
                if(password_verify($formPass, $hashedPass)) {

                    // correct login details!
                    // start the session
                    session_start();

                   // store data in SESSION variable
                    $_SESSION['loggedInUser'] = $user;
                    $_SESSION['loggedInEmail'] = $email;

                    header("Location: profile.php");
                } else { // hashed password didn't verify

                    // error message
                    $loginError = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Wrong username / password combination. Please try again.</div>";

                }
            } else { // there are no results in database

                $loginError = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>No such user in database. Please try again. <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a></div>";

            }

            // close the mysql connection
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

        <head>

             <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

             <title>Login</title>

             <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

              <!--HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries-->
            <!--WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file://-->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
         </head>

         <body>
             <div class="container">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <p class="lead">Use this form to log into your account</p>
                <?php echo $loginError; ?>

                <form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login-username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-username" placeholder="username" name="username">
                     </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login-password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-password" placeholder="password" name="password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="login">Login!</button>

                </form>

            </div>


    <!--Bootstrap JS-->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: question is if there's an existing hashed password in the db and whether the column's type is correct and long enough to hold the hash. 9 times out of 10, that's what the problem is. Posting db schema will take the guesswork out of it here.

Comment: Fred, the varchar on my db for password is set to 255. There is no existing hashed password as of yet. I am trying to create a login page to create one in the db.

Comment: there you go then. No passwords, no login. Create one with `password_hash()`.

Comment: Fred, I went ahead and entered a hashed password in my db. I can log in and out with it without any problems. So if you want to post your suggestion as an answer I will check it, although I still have the issue of the x on the error message not closing when clicking on it, but its a separate issue I guess.

Comment: JS isn't my strong point Daniel and won't be able to help for it, sorry about that.

Comment: One thing that could be the problem with the `x` issue, is that the jQuery library may not be loaded and may be required. I don't see it in your posted code. Check your console also.

Comment: Tip: `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"` can be written simply as `action=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Fred, the varchar on my db for password is set to 255. There is no existing hashed password as of yet. I am trying to create a login page to create one in the db. – Daniel Cortes"*

The problem is that there isn't a hashed password in your database to be compared with.

You will need to create one using the `password_hash()` function.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Sidenote:

Using `stripslashes(htmlspecialchars` doesn't safeguard against an SQL injection. It's best to use a prepared statement

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Is it really 'best' to use a prepared statement? Does `filter_var` & sanitizing fit into your scale?

Comment: @David Yes, when it comes to the database. Look at their `validateFormData()` function. That doesn't do much to prevent an SQL injection. What I wrote about that, doesn't have anything to do with `filter_var`, those are two different animals altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Also Your alert is not disappearing because Bootstrap depends on Jquery lib, and you  did not imported it.

Comment: Thank you jarguez, now its functioning, the new challenge is an address book I have created that is not adding new clients.